# formatting JSON output from dataframe

Tags: python, json

I new to coding. I am learning Python from the basics. I am trying to convert a data frame into JSON file using:

```py
json = data.to_json(orient='records')
```

this is the data frame:

```
value  range_lower  range_upper    fact  result  time
518.67  518.669999  518.670001  518.67        0     1
518.67  518.669999  518.670001  518.67        0     2
```

and I am getting the following output:

```
[{
    "value  range_lower  range_upper    fact  result  time": "518.67  518.669999  518.670001  518.67        0     1"
 },
 {"value  range_lower  range_upper    fact  result  time": "518.67  518.669999  518.670001  518.67        0     2"
 },
]


but I want it in the following format.



 [{
      value: 518.67
      range_lower: 518.669999
      range_upper: 518.670001
      fact: 518.67
      result: 0
      time: 1 
     },
    
     {
      value: 518.67
      range_lower: 518.669999
      range_upper: 518.670001
      fact: 518.67
      result: 0
      time: 2 
     },
    ]
```

Comment: Try  `data.to_json(orient='index')` That should do it. Check out the examples in the documentation for any further help -  [Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)

Comment: add the data frame sample in the question for better help

Comment: added sample dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **orient='records'** parameter of df.to_json().

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[518.67, 518.669999, 518.670001, 518.67, 0, 1],
        [518.67, 518.669999, 518.670001, 518.67, 0, 2]]

label = ['value', 'range_lower', 'range_upper', 'fact', 'result', 'time']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=label)  # Creates a data frame

json = df.to_json(orient='records')  # Computes the desired structure

print(json)  # To verify
```

Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'value':[518.67,518.67],'range_lower':[518.669999,518.669999],'range_upper':[518.670001,518.670001],'fact':[518.67,518.67],'result':[0,0],'time':[1,2]}
dp = pd.DataFrame(data)
dp.to_json('F:\\Name2.json',orient='records') ##to store the JSON data ini F: drive
```

Using this code will get your data in JSON format, but you have to use **online JSONFormatter** to correctly align the data as you desired. I am sharing the [link](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/), just copyAll the output data from the file and paste it in the website.